# iOS - MailCore - Crashes at MCData.cc - appendBytes

Tags: ios, crash, mailcore2, crittercism

I have MailCore integrated in my iOS project. Recenty, I have received in Crittercism (now Apteligent), several reports about crashes of the app caused by MailCore. The crashes are caused by the appendBytes method of MCData.cc, which is called from several methods of MailCore2. An example of a crash is:

Name: MCData.cc
Reason: SEGV_MAPERR

```
    libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000180c52240 _platform_memmove + 76
!   1   app 0x000000010029f6f4 appendBytes (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:123)
    2   app 0x000000010029f4d0 Data (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:84)
    3   app 0x000000010029f600 dataWithBytes (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:101)
    4   app 0x00000001002b997c dataAndFilterBccAndForEncryption (bool, bool) (MCMessageBuilder.cc:792)
    5   app 0x00000001002d64e8 -[MCOMessageBuilder data] (MCOMessageBuilder.mm:66)
```

Another example is the next trace:

Name: MCData.cc
Reason: SEGV_MAPERR

```
    0   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000001810d6240 _platform_memmove + 76
!   1   app 0x00000001001b76f4 appendBytes (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:123)
    2   app 0x00000001001b74d0 Data (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:84)
    3   app 0x00000001001b7600 dataWithBytes (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:101)
    4   app 0x00000001001f6424 -[MCOSMTPSession sendOperationWithData:] (MCOSMTPSession.mm:109)
```

And more:

Name: MCData.cc
Reason: SEGV_MAPERR

```
      libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000001819fe240 _platform_memmove + 76
!   1   app 0x000000010021f6f4 appendBytes (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:123)
    2   app 0x000000010021f4d0 Data (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:84)
    3   app 0x000000010021f600 dataWithBytes (char, unsigned int) (MCData.cc:101)
    4   app 0x0000000100255cf8 +[MCOAttachment attachmentWithData:filename:] (MCOAttachment.mm:63)
```

I have tried to reproduce the crashes, but everything appears to be OK. Any ideas, what is causing these crashes?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This crash doesn't look to be happened by Crittercism. If you still believe that this is somewhere related to the Crittercism, you can create a support ticket by sending an email to support@apteligent.com by mentioning the concerned App ID and the direct crash URL. Be noted that the email support is available for paid customers only.

Comment: I'm not saying that this crash is caused by Crittercism SDK. I wanted to say that I had received in Crittercism several reports about this crash. Sorry for the confusion